# What Wire Should be Used for a 40A 240V Circuit?

Tags: electrical, wiring, 240v, gauge

Given a 240V 40A circuit is there an official wire type that should be used? I assume there is a building code standard for this somewhere, but I don't really know where to look. I'd love if I could get some sort of official source.

For clarity, it would be helpful if the size could be given for copper and for aluminum, just so I'm not guessing at the material type of the answer.

Comment: Size is #8 copper, you asked “type” tho, and that’s more involved—what is the application? Is this single family residential or something else?  Are you planning conduit?

Comment: @Tyson So I've got a 40A breaker in. But I need to wire an electric vehicle charger. The charger is 32A, and it'll be the only thing on the circuit. Single family home, yes.

Comment: How long is the run and do you need to run it outside or is it all inside?

Comment: @JimmyJames The charger is actually located like 3' from the circuit panel. So there should be almost no load contribution from the wire. The ev charger is wired directly. With the wire being encased in conduit running directly from the panel to the charger. The charger is located "outside" but really in a porch.

Comment: Unless I am missing something, it seems you don't have any complicating factors.  There are users here that really know this stuff in-and-out so you should be able to get an authoritative answer.

Comment: @Harper Noted, comment removed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the entire route is conduit, you need 8 AWG THWN-2 copper. This will be individual wires, not a cable in a sheath.

You can also use 6 AWG Aluminum, but you won't find it.  You might find it if you shopped at a proper electrical supply house, but you'd get funny looks and an "are you sure".  In fact, **Just don't use aluminum** - installation is more sensitive to proper procedure, and at these small sizes, is really for wizards only.

If both panel and charger have steel chassis and the conduit is non-flexible and metallic, then you do not need a ground wire.  If you do need a ground wire, follow instructions but 10AWG Cu should suffice, in bare wire, green, or green/yellow.  These are the only permissible colors for grounds, and vice versa.  Bare aluminum grounds are illegal.

If neutral is needed (check instructions), use the same size wire as the main conductors, unless the instructions permit a smaller size.  Neutrals must be white or gray.  And vice versa.

Hot wires may be any other color(s) and your two hots may be the same color, feel free to be fanciful.  There really isn't any value in distinguishing them here.

Comment: I only hear bad things about aluminum.  Is there any reason why anyone (including wizards) would choose to use it?  I know there have been periods when price was a strong incentive but that aside...

Comment: @JimmyJames because if you go a lot deeper into the history of the aluminum wire problem, you realize the problem was non-wizards and the fact that *copper* is the bad actor.  Landing Al on Cu-only lugs caused the problem, but what do you use when you want a universal-donor lug? Aluminum. Seriously, look in your panel.  Al also has twice the conductivity of copper *by mass* and 12x the conductivity *by dollar*.  Copper is only better *by volume* due to its high density, but that only matters in armatures and cyclotrons.  And those hardly matter to the masses.

Comment: The problem with Al in small sizes is, you would need to be living inside an ecosystem where people who build small-wire terminations are *expecting* you to use aluminum, and have optimized for Cu-Al. That is not our world.  Even if they claim Al compatibility, you have to get the goop and the torque exactly right, and that's wizard stuff.

Comment: If 'wizard stuff' equals "knows how to read a spec and use a torque wrench", then I agree. But aluminum is not some magical, always-deadly conductor. Sometimes it's used for cost reasons.

Whether copper, aluminum, or solid gold, anyone dealing with 40A 240v circuits should follow code and know what they're doing. They don't need to be wizards ;)

Comment: @geerlingguy I completely agree that they **should**.